# Adding conflict entity in JpaRepository on conflict(409) responses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Spring Data REST returns a 409 status code and a JSON exception body when some client try to POST a duplicated entity in the database.

**JpaRepository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@PreAuthorize(whoCanPostAndUpdateTheirMessages)
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

}
```

**Request**

```
curl -u $AUTH -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "patient": "'$PATIENT_URL'", "date": "2014-01-01T00:00:0", "device": "00:00:00:00:00", "body": "this is a message" }' $SERVER/messages
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : {
      "cause" : null,
      "message" : "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uk_ofdr0s8f4x6q22veekngtwifd\"\n  Detail: Key (date, device)=(2014-01-01 00:00:00, 00:00:00:00:00) already exists."
    },
    "message" : "could not execute statement"
  },
  "message" : "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [uk_ofdr0s8f4x6q22veekngtwifd]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
```

Is possible to include the conflict entity (ID/URI) in the response body so client knows where to perform PUT/PATCH later on that resource?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to pass back a resource `uri` a location-Header

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid Entity purchase ,BindingResult result){
    boolean exits= false;
    // you checks here
    if(exits){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, "http://resource/id").build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("http://resource/id")).build();

}
```

Comment: Why is better to pass it in a header instead of in the body response?

Comment: makes more sense to use http location header to only share a resource `uri` nothing more, if a caller is interested, they will follow up with a  `http -get ` for a resource

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Use server-side validation means to detect a potential conflict (e.g. a duplicate user name or email address) and throw a meaningful exception that translates into a decent status code and message.

In general, don't reveal contextual information to the clients if not necessary as this could become a security risk leveraged by attackers.

### Details

I don't think it's a good idea to return additional information for a `POST` request here as you might reveal sensitive information about the existing entity on the attempt to create an entity.

On creation, all potentially conflicting properties should be validated by dedicated means on the server (i.e. if it's Spring Data REST using a corresponding event and/or validator) so that you can actually throw an appropriate exception. If you let the invalid data flow into your database, you basically don't get any further information about which other entity is causing the collision. That's basically a side-effect of passing invalid data through your entire application stack which shouldn't happen in the first place.

If the call returned information about the existing entity, it could be used to snoop for the identifier of that (e.g. trying to find the id of an already existing entity by trying to create one with a well-known username). For `PUT` and `PATCH` requests this is slightly different, as the client already knows about the identifier in the first place to issue the request against.

Comment: IMHO this security issue can be solved using @PreAuthorize. Right?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with @PreAuthorize. I wouldn't want to reveal such information to clients in the first place.

Comment: So... How do you know where to PUT/PATCH updates on that resource without an ID/URI?